# Replicate Weights, lmer and PISA data in R

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to understand and use PISA data in the most "accurate" way possible.

In the end, all I need are country means (BUT I want to control for individual level variables, so I have the country net effect, since I want to analyse education system characteristics). I am currently getting them with ranef out of a lmer multilevel model (with (1|CNT/SCHOOLID) and (1 |CNT) nesting).

I first thought of using the survey package, so I can include the replicate weights (svyrepdesign works), but then I cannot control for individual level variables (no multilevel possible).I tried svynlm - did not work, it does take way too long (48 hours and then does not converge).
I now figured out that for my case I should be using senate weights instead of the student final weights (not a problem so far, those I can include in lmer).

If I use mitools and lmer I have a multilevel model (with senate weights) and the Plausible Values, but not repweights. Since I am not including the se's in my further analysis, I could go with just senate weights, but I need a good explanation other than "technical consideration".

Does someone know a way out of this dilemma?

Comment: lots written here https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/archive/Program%20for%20International%20Student%20Assessment but it's very old and monetdblite is deprecated

Comment: I used your website already! Pretty helpful! I should have known you'd have something more laying around somewhere. Thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: You could also try the `RALSA` package which has a graphical user interface: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA For guides on how to use it, see here: http://ralsa.ineri.org/user-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Look at `BIFIEsurvey`. For two-level regressions, `BIFIE.twolevelreg` allows to use`PV` and replicate weights.

Consider also how to scale your weights: See here: Rabe-Hesketh, S., & Skrondal, A. (2006). Multilevel modelling of complex survey data. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A (General), 169, 805–827.

Comment: I did look at BIFIE at the time. It did not do what I wanted (I don't remember exactly why, but I was not able to achieve what I wanted with this package) I ended up combining the analyses from the PVs more or less manually while still being able to use all weights I needed. I am aware of the scaling problem (especially since the 2015 analyses).